# S3 Static Website displays different index.html on frontend of website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have static website on AWS. This website displays an error of missing index.html file so i checked the folder and index.html was missing so for confirming the issue I upload another websites index.html which is not public just to check the show. So my website displays the content so finally I upload the index.html file of my original website. But now issue is its showing the other website content on front end not the actual html which is the folder. When I click the index.html file and opens the object URL it redirects me to my original website content but when I open with domain name it shows the other website content.

This is the object URL:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/archiwiz.com/index.html

This is the website URL:

```
https://archiwiz.com/
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you have created a hosted zone with archiwiz.com domain in Route53.

Comment: @AnkushJain yes i have created hosted zone with archiwiz.com